# Huge amounts of locale queries clogging up drupal to 40 MB per request

Tags: database

I got an email today from my hosting company stating that they had to kill some processes of my site because it was using too much memory. Looking at the process table they provided, there were 10 processes of 40 MB, while my limit is 256 MB.

This poses me with two problems to solve.

1: Each page request drupal creates a process which uses 40MB of memory (which is of course killed again after the page is loaded). I've installed Devel and saw that each page makes around 900!! queries to the DB, most of which are from locale. All of them like this one:

```
   0.28270 locale P A E

   SELECT s.lid, t.translation, s.version 
       FROM locales_source s 
       LEFT JOIN locales_target t ON s.lid = t.lid AND t.language = :language 
       WHERE s.source = :source AND s.context = :context AND s.textgroup = 'default'
   default
```

How can I reduce this?

2: Apparently some1 put in 10 page requests at the exact same time (elapsed time of each process was equal). Is there something I can do about this?

If you need any more information please ask. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

900 queries looks far too much to me. By default, locale module caches all translations of strings that are less than 75 characters in 1 cache entry. This should prevent hundreds of separate translation string lookups.

The code involved (locale.module, function locale(), around line 668):

```
// Disabling the usage of string caching allows a module to watch for
// the exact list of strings used on a page. From a performance
// perspective that is a really bad idea, so we have no user
// interface for this. Be careful when turning this option off!
if (variable_get('locale_cache_strings', 1) == 1) {
  ...
  // Refresh database stored cache of translations for given language.
  // We only store short strings used in current version, to improve
  // performance and consume less memory.
  $result = db_query("SELECT s.source, s.context, t.translation, t.language FROM {locales_source} s LEFT JOIN {locales_target} t ON s.lid = t.lid AND t.language = :language WHERE s.textgroup = 'default' AND s.version = :version AND LENGTH(s.source) < :length", array(':language' => $langcode, ':version' => VERSION, ':length' => variable_get('locale_cache_length', 75)));
```

I guess that somehow 1 of the variables involved got changed on your site. Looking at the comment (*watch for the exact list of strings used on a page*) this could be the l18n_client module. Disable it on life sites.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Srry for the late answer as i was on vacation. The # of queries is now around 130. The PHP memory peak is still at 35 MB however. Is this just unavoidable or can I do something about this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Does your site use a caching system like Boost? Try installing the Drupal boost module and see if it helps. It is a static page caching system and needs to access the database only once.

Comment: Thank you. While my site also has a lot of unanonymous traffic, this sure made the anonymous traffic a hell of a lot faster.

Comment: If your site has a lot of anonymouse traffic then you could try using multiple levels of caching in your Drupal site to give an additional speed advantage. - You could try Memcached which caches the variables in memory and Varnish which acts a proxy caching system your user and your Apache. None of these are specific to Drupal though.